# change sign in specific rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my first post, so I am trying to do it in the right format. I have two columns with Text and Value and index Date.

```
Date  Zweck  Betrag                                 
2014-09-26 00:00:00   Gehalt    22.0  
2014-09-26 01:00:00     REWE     1.0  
2014-09-26 02:00:00    Edeka    76.0  
2014-09-26 03:00:00     Bike    51.0  
2014-09-26 04:00:00      ING    64.0  
2014-09-26 05:00:00  Allianz    93.0  
2014-09-26 06:00:00     Bahn     8.0  
2014-09-26 07:00:00  Kaufhof    33.0  
2014-09-26 08:00:00       CA     6.0  
2014-09-26 09:00:00    Shell    55.0
```

What I would like to do is to flip the sign in each row if Text is not Salary (so a negative value). I tried it with this approach but I doesn't work:

```
for r in np.arange(len(df)):
            if df.ix[r].Zweck != 'Gehalt':
                    betrag = df.ix[r].Betrag
                    df.loc[r, 'Betrag'] = -1 * betrag
```

Comment: `df.loc[df.Zweck != 'Gehalt', 'Betrag'] *= -1`

Comment: Thank you a lot coldspeed. Awesome reply!

Comment: @Piinthesky I usually have to say it, but you said it for me this time. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Accepting the answer is just upvoting or where do I have to do it?

Comment: You don't have the reputation score to upvote, yet. But you can accept answers for your question. There is a tick visible to below each answer vote counter. [See for explanation here.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) Increases also your own reputation score.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Option 1**
You don't have to iterate with a loop. Pandas' `loc` vectorises this replacement for you.

```
df.loc[df.Zweck != 'Gehalt', 'Betrag'] *= -1
```

```
df

                  Date    Zweck  Betrag
0  2014-09-26 00:00:00   Gehalt    22.0
1  2014-09-26 01:00:00     REWE    -1.0
2  2014-09-26 02:00:00    Edeka   -76.0
3  2014-09-26 03:00:00     Bike   -51.0
4  2014-09-26 04:00:00      ING   -64.0
5  2014-09-26 05:00:00  Allianz   -93.0
6  2014-09-26 06:00:00     Bahn    -8.0
7  2014-09-26 07:00:00  Kaufhof   -33.0
8  2014-09-26 08:00:00       CA    -6.0
9  2014-09-26 09:00:00    Shell   -55.0
```

The assignment is inplace, cheap, and fast.

---

**Option 2**
Alternatively, you could use `np.where`, which gives you a new series you can assign back.

```
df['Betrag'] = np.where(df.Zweck != 'Gehalt', df.Betrag * -1, df.Betrag)
```

```
df

                  Date    Zweck  Betrag
0  2014-09-26 00:00:00   Gehalt    22.0
1  2014-09-26 01:00:00     REWE    -1.0
2  2014-09-26 02:00:00    Edeka   -76.0
3  2014-09-26 03:00:00     Bike   -51.0
4  2014-09-26 04:00:00      ING   -64.0
5  2014-09-26 05:00:00  Allianz   -93.0
6  2014-09-26 06:00:00     Bahn    -8.0
7  2014-09-26 07:00:00  Kaufhof   -33.0
8  2014-09-26 08:00:00       CA    -6.0
9  2014-09-26 09:00:00    Shell   -55.0
```

---

**Option 3**
Another one, with `mask`/`where` -

```
df.Betrag = df.Betrag.where(df.Zweck != 'Gehalt', df.Betrag)
```

Or,

```
df.Betrag = df.Betrag.mask(df.Zweck == 'Gehalt', df.Betrag)
```

Or, you can use `df.update` instead, which eliminates the need to assign back.

```
df.update(df.Betrag.where(df.Zweck != 'Gehalt', df.Betrag))
```

```
df

                  Date    Zweck  Betrag
0  2014-09-26 00:00:00   Gehalt    22.0
1  2014-09-26 01:00:00     REWE    -1.0
2  2014-09-26 02:00:00    Edeka   -76.0
3  2014-09-26 03:00:00     Bike   -51.0
4  2014-09-26 04:00:00      ING   -64.0
5  2014-09-26 05:00:00  Allianz   -93.0
6  2014-09-26 06:00:00     Bahn    -8.0
7  2014-09-26 07:00:00  Kaufhof   -33.0
8  2014-09-26 08:00:00       CA    -6.0
9  2014-09-26 09:00:00    Shell   -55.0
```